# Java- 'if' statement gets ignored?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, javafx

My 'if' statement is getting ignored...
What is wrong with the code?

The code:

```
private ObservableList<String[]> fnlData;
.
.

for (int i = 0; i < fnlData.size(); i++){
    if (fnlData.get(i)!=null || fnlData.get(i)[indexC]!=null || fnlData.get(i).length > indexC+1) {
       fnlData.get(i)[indexC] = null;
    }
}
```

`fnlData.get(0)(=StringArray)` has just one element in it.
At the first loop (when i=0) it should skip the 'if'
Somehow it gets in and does  `fnlData.get(i)[indexC] = null;`
But because I dont have a 2nd element in the array, I get an error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `InvocationTargetException`

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it will skip the `if`? Since `fnlData.get(0)` is not null, it will proceed inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition is true if `fnlData.get(0)!=null` is true, which you claim it is.

If you require all the conditions to be true, use AND, not OR :

```
if (fnlData.get(i)!=null && fnlData.get(i)[indexC]!=null && fnlData.get(i).length > indexC+1)
```

Comment: Ah ok.
I had also to remove: fnlData.get(i)[indexC]!=null, then it worked